# Converting java.util.Date (01.01.0001) to java.time.LocalDate returns 29.12.0000

Tags: java, date, java-time

I want to parse `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate`
I found this code, when I searched for the problem:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.01.0001");
date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

if I have the `01.01.0001` as start date, I got problems:

```
date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

==> (java.time.LocalDate) 0000-12-29

`29.12.0000` and `01.01.0001` are not the same.

1. Why is the actual result different from the expected?
2. What can I do if I also want to receive the `LocalDate` with the value `01.01.0001`?

Informations to the time-zone:

```
ZoneId.systemDefault()
```

==> (java.time.ZoneRegion) Europe/Berlin

1. I think, the problem is this step: `date.toInstant()`
2. I do not think, that it is (only) a time-zone problem. If I test it with an different year. For example 1901, than it end at 31.12.1900.

```
        Date date0001 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.01.0001");
        System.out.println(date0001.toInstant());
```

==> 0000-12-29T23:00:00Z

```
        Date date1901 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.01.1901");
        System.out.println(date1901.toInstant());
```

==> 1900-12-31T23:00:00Z

Comment: What is your default timezone `ZoneId.systemDefault()`?

Comment: How did you create an instance of `java.util.Date` with `01.01.0001`?

Comment: better not use such an old class like `Date` (years are 1900-based, months 0-based, and days 1-based); if there is no option but to use it, maybe using a `Calendar` to get day, month and year to be used with `LocalDate.of(year, month, day)` (after adjusting the values) || some testing will show that `Date` and `Instant` will show different (textual) dates for the same *milliseconds* (for dates so far in the past as in this question)

Comment: I created the Date with Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.01.0001")

ZoneId.systemDefault()
=> (java.time.ZoneRegion) Europe/Berlin

Comment: I do not want to use Date. But it is part of legacy code.  To refactor the legacy code ist not an option at this point :(. So i have to convert the old Date to LocalDate.

Comment: as suggested, something *like*: `var c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(date); var local = LocalDate.of(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), 1+c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));` || BTW code posted in question should work with *more actual* dates (after 1582 - see [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar))

Comment: What about `date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();`? You can later convert to another `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` but initially and explicitly using UTC would get you rid of surprises like `29.12.0000` instead of the expected `01.01.0001`.

Comment: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.01.0001")` ← What time of day do think that Date has?  What timezone was used to determine that date?  You can answer these questions by printing the value of `date.toInstant()`.  This happens because a java.util.Date is not just a calendar date; it’s a date and time, always UTC, expressed in milliseconds.  SimpleDateFormat makes assumptions about the timezone, which makes SimpleDateFormat unreliable unless used very carefully.

Comment: @VGR but is that alone enough to explain the result being apparently 3 days back?

Comment: @user85421 Indeed it is not.  But avoiding SimpleDateFormat at least reduces the number of confounding and compounding factors.

Comment: @user85421 admittedly, I hadn't… Have you? However, I have now, and it turns out I should have tested it before ^^. There's no input value shown in the question, so I've used different ways to create one but none produced the expected value the way my previous comment suggests…

Comment: @deHaar you have suggested it, so why *must* **I** have tested it??? But there will be discrepancies between `Date` and `Instant` up to, partly including, year 1582 (I suppose it is related to the Julian, the Gregorian and the Proleptic Gregorian Calendars)

Comment: I didn't say you'd have to test it, just asked if you had…

Comment: Specify the result of `ZoneId.systemDefault()` in your test code.

Comment: Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HonzaZidek The down-votes may be due to a lack of important details, and a lack of an MCVE.

Comment: Then let's clarify the matter: You don't have to test it and I should have tested it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Multiple problems

- *1 day difference*: the time zone as already explained in other answers, that is, for example, midnight at the time zone `Europe/Berlin` corresponds to 23:00 the day before at `UTC` (no daylight saving time)
- *2 day difference*: the old classes (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`) are using the Julian Calendar up to October 1582, while the *new* classes in `java.time` are using the Proleptic Gregorian Calendar

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) we can see the difference between both, and following code confirms that:

```java
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // one error less
for (var year : List.of(1, 101, 201, 1401, 1501, 1601)) {
    var date = new Date(year-1900, 0, 10);
    var instant = date.toInstant();
    System.out.println(date.getTime() + " = " + date);
    System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli() + " = " + instant);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

> ```
>    -62134992000000 = Mon Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1
>    -62134992000000 = 0001-01-08T00:00:00Z
>    
>    -58979232000000 = Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 101
>    -58979232000000 = 0101-01-09T00:00:00Z
>    
>    -55823472000000 = Sat Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 201
>    -55823472000000 = 0201-01-10T00:00:00Z
>    
>    -17954352000000 = Mon Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1401
>    -17954352000000 = 1401-01-19T00:00:00Z
>    
>    -14798592000000 = Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1501
>    -14798592000000 = 1501-01-20T00:00:00Z
>    
>    -11643696000000 = Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1601
>    -11643696000000 = 1601-01-10T00:00:00Z
> ```

---

#### Javadoc

We can find the explanation for difference in the documentation (emphasis added):

- [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

  > Historically, in those countries which adopted the Gregorian calendar first, October 4, 1582 (Julian) was thus followed by October 15, 1582 (Gregorian). This calendar models this correctly. Before the Gregorian cutover, GregorianCalendar implements the Julian calendar. The only difference between the Gregorian and the Julian calendar is the leap year rule. **The Julian calendar specifies leap years every four years, whereas the Gregorian calendar omits century years which are not divisible by 400**.
- [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html)

  > The classes defined here represent the principle date-time concepts, including instants, durations, dates, times, time-zones and periods. They are **based on the ISO calendar system**, which is the de facto world calendar following the **proleptic Gregorian rules**.

---

#### Conclusion

If dealing with dates after 1582, `Date#toInstant`, `Instant#atOffset` (`Instant#atZone`) and `OffsetDateTime#toLocalDate` (`ZonedDateTime#toLocalDate`) can be used, taking care to use the correct time zone (offset.) Anyway, as already warned, using these classes is strongly discouraged!
Otherwise, for dates before/at 1582, you will need to first check which calendar was (should be) used to represent these dates.

For a Julian Calendar (before 1583), as I already commented, following or similar code can be used:

```java
var calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTime(date); 
var localDate = LocalDate.of(
    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
    1 + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),   // months are 0-based
    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 5):

## *java.time*

Understand that Java comes with two different date-time frameworks.

- One is terribly flawed, and is now [legacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system).
- The other is industry-leading, defined in JSR 310, with all classes found in the `java.time.*` packages.

Let's get the first moment of your year 1.

```
Instant yearOneStartInUtc = Instant.parse ( "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" );
```

> yearOneStartInUtc.toString() = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z

The `Z` on the end is pronounced “Zulu”, and represents an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC.

We can freely convert back and forth between the legacy and modern frameworks by calling new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date judStart = java.util.Date.from ( yearOneStartInUtc );
```

> judStart.toString() = Sun Jan 02 16:00:00 PST 1

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Notice that the `java.util.Date#toString` method lies to us. While `java.util.Date` represents a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero), its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating its text result. This is one of many reasons to **avoid this legacy class** as well as `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

Now we can look at the rest of your code.

### Adjusting between zones

You applied a time zone to an `Instant` to adjust from UTC. You neglected to tell us what is that time zone. So let's arbitrarily choose the time zone [`America/Edmonton`](https://time.is/Edmonton). This time zone uses an offset of several hours behind UTC.

```java
ZoneId zoneEdmonton = ZoneId.of ( "America/Edmonton" );
ZonedDateTime zdtYearOneStart = yearOneStartInUtc.atZone ( zoneEdmonton );
```

> zdtYearOneStart.toString() = 0000-12-31T16:26:08-07:33:52[America/Edmonton]

Notice the date differs from the input, 0000-12-31 versus 0001-01-01. The time differs as well, 16:26:08-07:33:52 versus 00:00:00. And therein lies our explanation.

Imagine that at that very moment, when the date and the year rolled over, Alice stood at the future site of the [Royal Observatory, Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich). She observed the current time of 00:00:00 on New Year's Day. But for Bob sipping nog over in Edmonton Alberta Canada, that same **simultaneous moment was New Year’s *Eve*, not New Year’s *Day*.** And when Bob looked up at the clock on his wall, he would see a time several hours *before* midnight. Alice was in “next year” 0001, while Bob was simultaneously in “last year” 0000.

For any given moment, the time and date vary around the globe by time zone.

So the difference in dates of January 1 versus December 31 makes sense. However, your result of December 29 does *not* make sense. You have neglected to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I suspect you have made a mistake.

Comment: timezone was given in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430683/converting-java-util-date-01-01-0001-to-java-time-localdate-returns-29-12-0000#comment136507148_77430683) and the next comment explains the *problem* - unfortunately not in the question itself

Comment: @user85421 On Stack Overflow, the reader is not expected to trawl through Comments to understand a Question. It is the author’s responsibility to edit their Question with all relevant facts.

Comment: I know and exactly why I commented to inform you; I am not the author and will not do theirs *job*  (as I already have commented: "unfortunately not in the question")

Comment: I am sorry. It was my fault not to edit my post. I am not used to write posts, because i can resolve moste of my problems by a web-searche. I have edited my original posts. thank you, for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> 29.12.0000 and 01.01.0001 are not the same.

Indeed. What we need to understand is the following: whenever you convert a time or a date to another timezone, if the two time-zones are different, then the resulting date might end up being different as well.

You have two date conversions:

- `atZone()`
- `toLocalDate()`

[atZone](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/instant-atzone-method-in-java-with-examples/) returns `ZonedDateTime`. `toLocalDate` converts your date into another timezone'd date: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html.

[There are more than 24 time-zones.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/current-number-time-zones.html)

[image]

So, if you do two conversions in this manner, then it is quite possible that the two conversions in total subtract at least 24 hours and therefore result in two date differences.

I'm puzzled to see that you actually have a 3-day difference. You will need to break up your code and see where the data changes actually happen. They could be time-zone differences like I described. Or they could be some bugs either in your code or the legacy library. Maybe you have more conversions.

A very "simple" way to go back in time in this manner to convert actual dates to time-zones and forget the hours. Then, if the time-zone changes have decreasing time-zone offsets, then you repeatedly get subtracted days.