# LocalDateTime before 0 year transform to/from Timestamp is wrong

Tags: java, timestamp

If LocalDateTime is before 0000-00-00 00:00:00, when transforming to Timestamp, year of Timestamp is wrong, for example, -1996 in LocalDateTime will transform to -1997 in Timestamp. -1996 is leap year, -1997 is not, so you can not transform -1997-02-29 in Timestamp to LocalDateTime

```
 LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(-1996,2,29,10,10,10,100);
 Timestamp timestamp =  Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime); // timestamp is B.C.E. 1997-02-29T10:10:10.000
 LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = timestamp.toLocalDateTime(); // throw exception[ Invalid date 'February 29' as '1997' is not a leap year]
```

Comment: In actual fact, year -1997 was not a leap year.  Leap years did not exist until the year 45 BC.  Before that time, there weren't 12 months in a year.  You also need to remember that there was no year 0.  The calendar goes from -1 BC directly to 1 AD.  That adds an extra offset to periods that cross the BC/AD border.

Comment: *probably* same reason as [Converting java.util.Date (01.01.0001) to java.time.LocalDate returns 29.12.0000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77430683/85421) - `java.time` classes (like `LocalDateTime`) use a different calendar than the older classes (like `Timestamp` )

Answer (score 1):

> -1996 in LocalDateTime will transform to -1997 in Timestamp

This is not wrong. The meaning of "year" for `LocalDateTime` and `Timestamp` is different.

A `LocalDateTime` "year" value of 1 means AD 1, and a value of 0 means 1 BC, and so on, so a value of -1996 represents the year 1997 BC.

A `Timestamp` "year" is a number such that adding 1900 to it gives you the actual year (see the docs for [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html)), though a lot of its APIs automatically adds/subtracts 1900 for you. Worse, the year that you get by adding 1900 is always positive, so this is kind of like a "year of era".

When you print the `Timestamp` out, 1900 is automatically added to show you the year 1997. The number is not negative, but the `Timestamp` actually represents an instant in BC.

So the conversion *to* `Timestamp` is correct, but when converting *from* `Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime`, the `toLocalDateTime` method just gets the year from the `Timestamp` and adds 1900, then uses that as the year for `LocalDateTime`. So yo actually get a `LocalDateTime` representing a date in AD. Since AD 1997 is not a leap year, the conversion fails.

See also the [source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/Timestamp.java#L518) for `toLocalDateTime`.

Arguably, this could be seen as a bug in `toLocalDateTime`, but I don't think `Timestamp` was designed to represent *dates* in BC in the first place (it can represent *instants* of those times just fine though).

**I suggest that you should stop using `Timestamp` altogether. Use `Instant` if you want to represent a moment in time.**

To do this roundtrip, you would need to check if the `Timestamp` is before AD 1, and if so, use `-(getYear() + 1899)` as the year for the `LocalDateTime`.

Here is a sketch of what it would look like:

```
// getAD1EpochMillis() is a method you should write to get the epoch millis
// of AD 1 January 1st midnight, in the system timezone. 
// You should use the old APIs to do this, because timezones in java.time behaves differently.
if (timestamp.getTime() < getAD1EpochMillis()) {
    return LocalDateTime.of(
            -(timestamp.getYear() + 1899),
            timestamp.getMonth() + 1,
            timestamp.getDate(),
            timestamp.getHours(),
            timestamp.getMinutes(),
            timestamp.getSeconds(),
            timestamp.getNanos()
    );
} else {
    return timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
}
```

The meaning of "before AD 1" depends on timezone, but the `java.time` APIs calculates timezones differently from the old API (e.g. `java.time` takes local mean time into account before timezones were standardised). This is also why you can't just do this to roundtrip:

```
timestamp.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()
```

All of that is to say, the old API is very bad at doing historical dates. Please migrate to `java.time`.