# Can someone help me to understand what happen when converting from Date to Instant

Tags: java, date

For following code

```
String sTime = "0001-01-01 00:00:00";
Date date = null;
try{
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(sTime);
}
catch(Exception e){
    
}
Instant yearOneStartInUtc = Instant.parse ( sTime );

System.out.println(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
System.out.println(yearOneStartInUtc.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));

System.out.println();
System.out.println("UTC for now is " +   Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
System.out.println("UTC for now in Date is " + new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
```

Why is the difference of first two instant are diff by 2 days?

The output:

```
0000-12-29T19:03:58-04:56:02[America/New_York]
0000-12-31T19:03:58-04:56:02[America/New_York]

UTC for now is 2024-02-15T16:03:25.401665-05:00[America/New_York]
UTC for now in Date is 2024-02-15T16:03:25.419-05:00[America/New_York]
```

Above is what I tried

Comment: Note that `String sTime = "0001-01-01 00:00:00";` represents a `LocalDateTime` (a date and a time without a time zone), not a `Date` or an `Instant`.

Comment: this was asked before: `Instant` and `Date` use different calendars -- see answers of: [Converting java.util.Date (01.01.0001) to java.time.LocalDate returns 29.12.0000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77430683/85421)